# jQuery/javascript check if anything is loading

Tags: jquery, events, networking, loading, traffic

Once a document is fully loaded, my javascript starts changing things like img sources and background images.
These changes happen in different ways (by preloading them in JS or by directly changing the `src` attribute for exemple). However, for these changes new files need to be loaded.
These changes happen randomly, with random sources to random elements, so I can't provide a list of elements or sources.

At certain moments in time, my javascript (jQuery) needs to check if anything is still loading, or if everything is completely loaded.

In other words, I need a way to check if any network traffic is going on or not.

Ideally, I wan't a way to set the variable `loading` to true every time a request is being made to load a file, and to set that variable to false ones the loading process if complete, so I can use something like `while (loading==true) {loopscript()}` to loop some script while loading.

Is there any jQuery way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JQuery load event, but you will need to make sure the setInterval call is embedded in the head. The below example is to load a page with an image taking 5000ms to load. It output to the console every 1000ms.

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  var intervalID = setInterval(function() {
    console.log("loading");
  }, 1000);
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
  jQuery(window).load(function() {
    clearInterval(intervalID);
  });
  </script>
  <img src="http://deelay.me/5000/http://deelay.me/img/5000ms.gif">
</body>
```

Comment: huh? Please do provide a demo that meets OP requirements using this

Comment: I tried doing this before, but using $(window).load(...) doesn't seem to solve my problem. The event doesn't trigger every time something starts loading, which would be necessary for what I need. Instead, it looks like it only triggers when the window loads and that's it.

Comment: @charlietfl I should have tried my method first. I tested but it did not work. Sorry about that.

Comment: @eds1999 I've made it working and provided an example

Comment: @volatilevar Thanks but this still doesn't answer my question. As I wrote "Once a document is fully loaded...", so the network traffic I'm trying to detect starts after the page is fully loaded. The method you provide triggers some code when the page loads, but not when a loading request is made later, for example when you later try $("#someimg").attr("src","http://somesource/")

Comment: @eds1999 I see. There is no simple way in this case. You probably need a queue/array of promises and periodically check whether the queue is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a promise for each action using [`$.Deferred`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/) and push all the promises to array.

Then use [`$.when()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) to update the loading variable after all the promises have resolved.

Each individual promise would need to be resolved within a load event handler for images or whatever other event might be triggered when that action is completed